# Show Linkedin Articles Feed on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I need to show Linkedin articles feed on wordpress as can I do for instagram, facebook and other social network.

I didn't find any plugin to do this and I can't copy each time the single article embed code on client news page on his new website.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing after a request of one of my customers but there is no api or thing like that to display linkedIn publications on an external website.

Comment: It seems strange to me that there's no way to do this. I read that something has changed since March but I can't say to my customers that he has to insert manually each time the embed code of an article he created on linkedin in order to visualize it on his website too...

Comment: Mmmmhhhh maybe something to do with this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/publication but I'm not sure if publications are what pple are posting on their linked profile... I've found something with the V1 of the REST Api too... at the end of the page it could be something useful too, if it works. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api you can still explore this way. If it works it could be very interesting then !